# Why sharedpreference value not getting in when retrieving?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I aaded three shared preferences as below code. And I am able to retrieve onl n shared preference value.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("Loggedin",true);
            editor.putString("userId",userid);
            editor.putString("pwd",password);
            editor.apply();
            editor.commit();
```

I used the following code for retrieving from another activity. I am able to retrieve only the boolean value. Other values are not there. getting the default value for the string values. please help me.

```
   SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

                Boolean loggedin=preferences.getBoolean("Loggedin", false);
                String userId=preferences.getString("userId", "0");
                String pwd=preferences.getString("pwd", "0");
```

Comment: do you get values on another activity ?

Comment: Boolean loggedin=preferences.getBoolean("Loggedin", false); how ru inniating preferences

Comment: @Singh yes. i am retrieving values on another activity

Comment: Post full code, how're you instantiating your preferences while you trying to retrieve values from it.

Comment: Why do you use both `apply()` and `commit()`?!

Comment: Why are you using   `editor.apply();`

Comment: editor. apply() or editor.commit() is enough..anyhow the problem is not with that. i tested it

Comment: Any other place are you using    `SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: @Piyush yes. I am using

Comment: Either use `apply()` or `commit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
String userId=preferences.getString("userId", null);
                String pwd=preferences.getString("pwd", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

check first the value u store in preferences are stored or not
using this code

```
Boolean loggedin=preferences.getBoolean("Loggedin", false);
 String userId=preferences.getString("userId", null);
 String pwd=preferences.getString("pwd", null);


if(userId==null || pwd==null)
{
//data not therer
}
else
{
//do something with data
}
```

and let me know if any error occured..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not getting the `SharedPreferences` in a correct way.
See the doc for ex: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
    getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Also, you don't need to call `apply()` AND `commit()`. Just one of those is enough. See the javadoc for the differences btw them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Boolean loggedin=preferences.getBoolean("Loggedin", false);
            String userId=preferences.getString("userId", "");
            String pwd=preferences.getString("pwd", "");

if(userId==null || userId==""||pwd==null ||pwd=="")
{

}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code in this way.

**Set values in First Activity**

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("Loggedin",true);
    editor.putString("userId",userid);
    editor.putString("pwd",password);
    editor.apply();
```

**Retrieve value in Second Activity**

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            Boolean loggedin=preferences.getBoolean("Loggedin", false);
            String userId=preferences.getString("userId", "");
            String pwd=preferences.getString("pwd", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Used in that way for retrieve values from shared preferences for your code.**

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

            Boolean loggedin=preferences.getBoolean("Loggedin", false);
//Checking the value of userId and pwd,if they are null then there is no values of userId and pwd other than default.
             if (userId != null && pwd != null) {
        String userId = preferences.getString("userId", "0");
        String pwd = preferences.getString("pwd", "0");
    } else {
        String userId = "0";
        String pwd = "0";
    }
```